# ¿Se puede obtener el nombre de la red wifi conectada actualmente en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Hay alguna manera de poder el nombre de la red wifi conectada actualmente?

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa que obtiene algo de información del equipo y la muestra al usuario
he podido obtener varios datos del sistema tales como nombre del equipo, nombre del usuario, su ip, su mac y sobre el SO en general

Comment: Personalmente, creo que esta pregunta tiene más sentido en google que en SO. Si tienes un problema lo correcto es investigar por ti mismo... es la única manera de aprender. Si en vez de esforzarnos venimos a que nos den las soluciones hechas de primeras nunca aprendemos nada. Además, según [ask] y [help] una pregunta debe demostrar esfuerzo por parte del autor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hasta donde se esos datos no se podría obtener directamente con Java, la forma más simple de obtener la información de la red seria ejecutando un comando de PowerShell con Java.

Primero utilizaremos una librería que simplifica la ejecución de comandos en PoweShell esta es la dependencia:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.profesorfalken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jPowerShell</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Comando para obtener el nombre de la red
      String command = "Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name";
     
     // Ejecución del comando con JPowerShell
      System.out.println(PowerShell.executeSingleCommand(command).getCommandOutput());
  }
```

Comment: El OP no ha especificado si quiere poder ejecutar en distintos sistemas operativos, pero es importante tener en cuenta que esta solución te limita a Windows

Comment: @PabloLozano estoy 100 % de acuerdo, por eso comentaba que Java nativamente no tiene la opción, si se necesita ser multiplataforma se puede crear una clase para verificar el sistema operativo y utilizar el mismo enfoque de ejecutar un comando en la consola, claro que habría que manejar manualmente la llamada con Runtime.getRuntime().exec y buscar el comando de cada plataforma.